# Angular / Angularfire2 Cannot find a differ supporting object

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm having trouble assigning firebase db.list() return to a variable

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
//import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastrar-pessoa-lista',
  templateUrl: './cadastrar-pessoa-lista.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastrar-pessoa-lista.component.css']
})
export class CadastrarPessoaListaComponent implements OnInit {

  pessoas: AngularFireList<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    **console.log('antes...: ' + typeof this.pessoas); // == undefined**
    this.pessoas = db.list('pessoas');
    **console.log('antes...: ' + typeof this.pessoas); // == object**
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

ng serve works, but component doesn't, the error in devtools is:

> AngularFireList Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object
>   Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables
>   such as Arrays

So, [documentation list() deals with a Generic type](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/database.ts), as long as I understood:

```
list<T>(pathOrRef: PathReference, queryFn?: QueryFn): AngularFireList<T> {
    const ref = getRef(this.app, pathOrRef);
    let query: DatabaseQuery = ref;
    if(queryFn) {
      query = queryFn(ref);
    }
    return createListReference<T>(query);
  }
```

What is going on, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.list()` retrieve an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) value (async) - [manual](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md). So you need to `subscribe()` it before get `pessoas` value.

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

ngOnInit() {
    let pessoasObservable = db.list('pessoas').subscribe(pessoas => {
        this.pessoas = pessoas;
    });
}
```

Best practice tells us to use `onInit()` instead of `constructor()` - [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-c9930c209a42)

Comment: What is "Pessoas" in pessoas as Pessoas? I have no Pessoas type. I can't cast to array or ArrayFireList either

Comment: Sorry, I think you had a Pessoa's class/interface. If you don't use type like `pessoas : Pessoas`, just delete it.

Comment: I need an Observable. This helped me too: Developers normally need to make use of arrays in order to display data. However, firebase does not store any data in array form. Instead, it uses a JSON-like structure. That being said, to make it easier for everyone to wrap their heads around retrieving data from firebase as an array, angularfire gives you $firebaseArray(), which essentially converts the data from a certain location and returns you that same data inside of an array (a read-only pseudo-array).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem's cause are you returning a dbReference to template. Try do this modifications

```
  pessoasRef: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  pessoas: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {

  this.pessoasRef = db.list('pessoas');
  this.pessoas = this.pessoasRef.valueChanges();
```